# Flutter permission handler showing different app name

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using permission_handler plugin to get access of gallery and media for image upload. Issue is the permission dialog showing different

in android.xml file i have

```
    android:name="DOR"
    android:label="DOR"
```

and in build.gradle and I have DOR in my app name Don't know why I get this WPS Office

[image]

Comment: Is that name something that was used earlier? Uninstall the application and try again.

Comment: flutter clean and flutter pub get will resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Ctrl + shift + f(windows) or cmd + shift+f (Mac) and find WPS office. If you find it somewhere please replace it. If you don't find it and invalidate cache and restart. Run flutter clean and then build the app